# Logic: syntactic proofs in axiom system $K_n$; $K_i(p\implies q) \implies (K_ip \implies K_iq)$

Tags: logic

I know how to do syntactic proofs but I don't know which tautology I need to start from in this case.
$$K_i(p\implies q) \implies (K_ip \implies K_iq).$$
I tried $(p\implies q) \implies (p\implies q)$ but I don't think it's right and I can't get the result out of this, can anyone help?

Comment: What proof system are you using? And what axioms are you assuming? The statement you're trying to prove looks suspiciously like Axiom K in [modal logic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic#Axiomatic_systems), especially since a lot of people use $K_i$ for the modality "agent $i$ knows"... But in modal logic the statement you're attempting to derive is an axiom. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: I just reread your title. Would you mind elaborating on what "Kn" is? Again, from the modal logic angle, K and N are the axiom and inference rule characterizing a normal modal logic. But again, in this system K is an axiom, so I'm still confused.

Comment: It is what you first guessed, $K_i$ means "agent i knows..", this is an example from my lecture notes https://imgur.com/a/CZybi62